# Wordpress 'limit_login_lockouts' using internal ip adress

Tags: login

i'm using AWS - Elastik Beanstalk for a Wordpress page.
I have the problem that wordpress blocked the internal IP "172.31.47.52".
But this is the private IP in the local Network and not the Forwarded IP.

Is there a way to tell Wordpress to use the right IP at this point?
Couse Wordpress locks up the login page after a short time couse bots want's to login.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a Nodejs/Nginx stack under AWS/ElasticBeanstalk. I was having an issue where I needed my server to log the full path to the request, but all it was logging was requests from the load balancer, (172.31.xx.xx). I had to get AWS support to help debug the issue, and they were able to get the Nginx server to properly log the requests, so I had access to the full path, not the load balancer.

I imagine to fix this, you will have to do a similar change to PHP.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se] and thanks for contributing to our pool of answers. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.